# Block access to folder or file in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, security, passwords

Is there any way to block access to some particular file or folder in MacOS X, so that it can be protected by password, system-wide?
I want to use it in Cocoa based program, but before that I just want to know at least general possible methods of accomplishing it.
As far as I know POSIX file access system doesn't allow to protect something with password.
I was thinking about creating additional user account with dedicated password and then setting this user as an owner of a file with `chmod`. In terminal it seemed to work, but that is quite bad way, I think, since that is a sort of permission problem. And you need to change user in terminal for that. I don't think that can be done if one wants to access it through regular application like Finder.
So does anybody know better ways?

Comment: You're probably better off asking this question on Superuser or AskDifferent (Apple)

Comment: Thank you. I've posted. But is AskDifferent really more active than StackOverflow?

Comment: AFAIK, Stack Owerflow is the most active site in the network. It is however a site for **programming-related questions**, so your question is a bit off-topic here.

Comment: Actually I am asking about programmatic ways of doing this. So I don't think it's off-topic.

Comment: In that case you should make it clear in the question. For example, specify for what programming language are you looking for a solution, what have you tried so far etc. The question as it is reads as it being a general computer usage question.

Comment: I think you'd be better off if you created an encrypted file that has all the folder/file data as you can easily access any folder with the administrator password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a password protected "folder" you can use an encrypted disk image and mount it at the location you require the folder. The command `hdiutil` can be used to create, mount, unmount etc. such disk images. Use the the `-plist` option to easily drive the `hdiutil` command from Objective-C.

Comment: Will it mount the disk as a regular folder?

Comment: All disks are mounted as regular folders under Mac OS X. The default location for these folders is /Volumes, but you can change this. Just insert, say, a USB stick and you'll find a folder created under /Volumes.

Comment: And am I right thinking that if I mount dmg image not in /Volumes/ but in another location, it will not also show up in the Devices section of Finder Sidebar? That is what I want, actually.

Comment: @BartoNaz: pass the `-nobrowse` flag to `hdiutil` to avoid the volume showing up in the Finder.

Comment: @pmjorda: Thank you. I think solution is going to be what I've been looking for. Thank you all.